# DjangoUnicodeDecodeError when reading model from MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode

Ok I'm stumped. I have a very simple database query with Django models as follows:

```
items=models.Item.objects.all()
```

As soon as I try to run this I get an exception:

DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 1: invalid continuation byte. You passed in 'E\xe4I\n\x01\x80\xc0\xc9\xa3\xd0-m\xd1c%\x7f' ()

There is nothing particularly complex about the Item model. I went into MYSQL and ran show table status and all tables use utf8_general_ci collation. I have no idea how to fix this. Any ideas?

I should also mention that I am running this inside some code where I run a Django models management command. In other words, in my models/management/commands folder I have a python file (say do_stuff.py) and I execute that with ./manage.py do_stuff. So this is all running from the command line, ie no browser involved, no templates, etc. Just a custom Djanago command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a unicode expert, but it seems that your data is not utf-8, but rather utf-16.

You can try:

```
In [10]: b = b'E\xe4I\n\x01\x80\xc0\xc9\xa3\xd0-m\xd1c%\x7f'

In [11]: b.decode('utf-8')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-dbeeccecf491> in <module>()
----> 1 b.decode('utf-8')

/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc in decode(input, errors)
     14 
     15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
---> 16     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
     17 
     18 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

In [12]: print b.decode('utf-16')
੉老지킣洭揑缥
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot even get the data to decode. It throws an exception as soon as I execute the Django query.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that I had one field in Item that was encrypted data. It looks like there was some issue in encoding - perhaps the default encoding for the database was not utf8. In any case, I was able to avoid this problem by just emptying out this field, since I didn't need it. Not the most satisfying solution but at least it let me keep going. I suspect the best solution is indeed to make sure that the DB is formatted to use UTF8 by default before putting anything in it.